# Check when password was last changed

Tags: linux, windows

How do I check when the password was last changed for some user? I would like to do it both on Windows and Linux, can you guide me a little how can I do that?

Comment: ... or do you mean you want your application to check when the user's password was last changed?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**In Linux:**

```
chage -l {username}
```

**In Windows:**

```
net user {username} | find /I "Password last set"
```

**In Windows (user part of a domain):**

```
net user {username} /DOMAIN | find /I "Password last set"
```

Comment: well it would be if it were to be edited like "How to check when password was last changed in any OS" and the answers were accordingly. Might provide a good reference/cheat list.

Comment: Output from `net user` is localised, so you'll need to know the actual translation for "Password last set" in your server.

Comment: Perhaps providing examples along with unknown syntax is not as bad idea as could appear.

Answer (score 3):

***nix**

Check out the command [`chage`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?chage+1) or  [`getprpw`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1m/getprpw/)

**Windows**

`net user UserName` has the information in it

Answer (score -2):

> net user UserName /DOMAIN | find /I "Password last set"

This command is useful and was able to check my last password change date and time.