# is there a way to check out that my all shell users has changed their password

Tags: linux, bash, unix, centos

is there any way to find out that my all linux users has changed the passwords.
As recently I made a security policy which allow users to change their password at next logins.

OS: **Centos 5.9**

Comment: ask it in [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [linux&unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can see the logs from `/var/log`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check when password was last changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781144/check-when-password-was-last-changed)

Comment: Thanks all for your answers, I found it via chage -l (username) where it has mentioned all things like "Last password change" which I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Either

1. Check your `/var/log/auth.log` `/var/log/secure.log` or wherever Centos syslogs that to; OR
2. Retrieve your `/etc/shadow` from your backup immediately preceding this event, and use `diff` to compare against your current `/etc/shadow`. You will be able to see the hashed password changes. Some lines might show up if other things have changed, but these are relatively rare and can be weeded out manually.